# Is it possible to add a form to a TreeView?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, treeview, treenode

I want to create a TreeView that contains complex forms of `EmployeeNode` as nodes. When you add the node I will call `InitializeComponent()`. So that the expected result will be something like

[image: this]

Or codewise:

```
EmployeeNode EMPND = new EmployeeNode(new Employee());
EMPND.Draw();
VisualTree.Nodes.Add(EMPND);

//Draw (at EmployeeNode form class)
public void Draw()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

Is this possible?

*edit*

If this cant be done using TreeView, I am open to hear about other ways to store forms, other then TreeView, that offers similar hierarchy - based WinForm visual solutions (maybe a generic version?)

Comment: A treeview you can add Controls like textboxes and Listboxes. : treeView1.Controls.Add(textbox1);

Comment: @jdweng yes but can it add a form?

Comment: A form is a control.  Probably better to use Panel where you can add controls like form and have less overhead.

Comment: The TreeView won't interact with anything that isn't a node, and a Form (or Control) is not a node.   Based on the image, you should just create a custom control.

Answer (score 0):

Set the TopLevel property of the form you want to add as false.

```
var form = new Form { TopLevel = false };
treeView.Controls.Add(form);
form.Show();
```